# ImageResizer - Is it possible to use an AnimatedGif as a Watermark?

Tags: imageresizer

I'm trying to use an animated gif as a watermark over a static jpg.  I've got the AnimatedGif plugin installed along with the PrettyGifs and Watermark plugins.

I'm resizing and cropping the jpg to match the size of the animated watermark with querystring paramters as follows:

```
2.jpg?maxwidth=640&width=640&height=640&mode=crop&anchor=topcenter&format=gif&watermark=animated
```

In my web.config I have the 640 x 640 animated gif setup as follows

```
<image name="animated" path="~/watermarks/animation.gif" />`
```

The resulting image is strictly the first frame of the animated gif, so I'm wondering if what I'm trying to do is even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to make the gif the primary image, and the jpeg the watermark instead, and make it a background underlay, adding margins to match the jpeg's size.

I think this would produce extremely large images that couldn't be used on the web, though.

Comment: Awesome.  Why didn't I think of that?  I'll give it a shot.